120V on fridge door handle when ground broken
Looking at a friend's fridge that I discovered had a broken ground pin in its power plug
Fridge chassis was causing painful shock when touching it.  I measured 120V from fridge chassis to ground.  I found the ground pin missing from the plug, and assumed a damaged wire in the fridge was energizing the chassis but inspected inside fridge and all wiring was in perfect condition.
Connecting the fridge chassis to ground did not cause a short circuit.  I replaced the plug with a correctly wired one and the fridge functions normally and no longer causes electric shock. Plugging the new plug into a nearby, tested, GFCI outlet does not trigger it.
I'm aware of phantom voltage caused by inductance that can be measured with meters and aware fridges can sometimes have some current to ground through inductance but never heard of or experienced it so significantly it would cause painful electric shock. And, that theory would suggest A GFCI would be triggered.
Any understanding of what might have been going on, and whether this is normal for a fridge with severed ground connection or whether there may be some remaining fault with it now that the plug is repaired and there are no symptoms?

I had something that sounds similar, a shock from the refrigerator handle. I improvised some testing equipment, turned out that wall outlet had a "hot ground. "  In sum: the refrigerator need not be the problem.

Tx.  I did some tests on the outlet and it seemed normal.  Since the fridge's ground pin was missing, nothing points to a problem with the outlet's ground.

Is it a simple fridge or does it have some electronics in it, such as a digital temperature display? Maybe the electronics have a switched-mode PSU designed to use ground for EMI suppression. Without the ground connected to ground, there could be a noticeable voltage on the chassis.

Inductance will not trigger the GFCI: The GFCI measures differences in current flow on L and N, and trip if that exceeds a certain threshold for a certain time. Inductance happens in metallic parts with no direct connection to either L or N, much like the secondary side of a transformer. I had something similar: got an electric shock when touching my dishwasher. Turned out every chassis of every device on that circuit seemed to be hot (as far as a simple voltage tester was concerned). The cause ultimately was a broken ground connection in the panel. No GFCI tripped.

@andrewmorton that should be an answer.  Preferably with references or steps to test it if possible.  I once had a laptop computer, 19VDC coming out of the all-plastic three-pin power brick, and the laptop metal parts were zappy when plugged in to a two pin outlet with a cheater plug.  I don't know if I'm correct in connecting these but it seems relevant and it's the most viable suggestion so far.

It only takes a few mA at 120 V to get a noticeable tingle. You've already determined that the current leakage is very low -- too low to trigger a GFCI -- so if you want to track this down further, you can disconnect the ground wire from the new plug and place an AC milliammeter in series between the ground wire (or the metal chassis itself) and the outlet's ground to actually measure the leakage current. It would be best to use a fused milliammeter if you have one.
How about that old analog Micronta Range Doubler that you haven't touched in years? Perfect for this task.
Once you have a good handle on the actual current, you can try various measures to isolate and identify the source of leakage by monitoring the meter display while disconnecting refrigerator components.

See if disconnecting the compressor's capacitor (if any) makes a change.
See if the current changes or disappears with the compressor running
/ not running.
See if unplugging the compressor's electrical connector makes a
change.
And so on with the defrost timer, defrost heater, mullion heater
(embedded around the door), ice maker, circulating fan, light socket,
water/ice dispenser, control board, and so on.

Something, somewhere in the refrigerator is leaking current, so if you can measure it and display it continuously, you'll be able to find it.

The capacitor (if any) is the first suspect.

Permitted leakage for grounded, stationary, motor-operated appliances is 3.5 mA.

Another way to avoid damaging an ammeter could be to start with a 100 ohm resistor in series, then 50 ohm, both of which will limit current to only a few amps even if there was otherwise a short circuit (my multimeter has a 10A unfused as well as smaller fused ranges).  Either do some math to estimate the rest of the "internal" resistance and expected current with no added resistor, or just keep using smaller resistors if you have some like a 10 ohm should limit current to 12 amps RMS worst case, and actually still be pretty small relative to whatever sizeable resistance actually exists.

@PeterCordes Thanks Peter, good info. He knows that it's only milliamps that he's dealing with because he tried plugging into a working GFCI and it didn't pop. No harm in taking precautions though!

Oh right, so you're unlikely to actually pop a fuse. So good advice in this case to just go with something like the highest fused range on your multimeter at first.  (Maybe still with a resistor in series, especially if you aren't 100% sure what two things you're connecting between if you have multiple wires exposed!)

Most appliances are hard to check all of the wiring.
Chassis to anything should read 0.  120v to ground means hot is touching chassis somehow.
You need a good connection between hot/ground or hot neutral to cause a breaker short trip.  Most breakers will be quite happy not to trip with a partial short.  7 amps for the fridge and up to/just above breaker size to ground.  Lost money.
Most of us do not have the special testing equipment to check for bad wire insulation.
Imagine plugging it into a GFCI protected circuit will pop the GFCI.  This is what GFCIs were made for.  Partial shorts that might kill, but not trip a common breaker.
Grounded or not, the chassis should not give a shocking experience without a problem in the wiring.
Instead of the fridge costing 10 dollars a month, it is now costing 50 to 100 dollars since the ground is bleeding off power.

Damn that's obvious (now).  :). Easy to test.

Nearby GFCI does not pop with fridge plugged in it. Its test button does.  Would have been a lot easier to measure current to ground before I fixed it but I think the GFCI test means <?mA

@jay613  I believe ? is about 5 or 6.  Do not know what telephone lines deliver in amps/mA, but twisting the bare wires with bare fingers while laying on slightly damp ground(crawl space) is interesting.

@crip659 - Especially when someone calls in!

Old -style fully analog telephone ringer voltage was 90 volts, if I remember correctly. I have no idea whether that's still true.

I updated the question to address your theory, which was excellent, but appears wrong. I think.  Also, I do not have and have never used insulation testing equipment but I don't think you can use it on a finished appliance.

@keshlam every voip box I've tested is capable of ringing my 1970s phone with a huge double clanger in it.  But only one recognizes its pulse dialling.  :(

A power supply designed to use ground for EMF noise suppression but severed from ground
Picking up on @AndrewMorton's comment above and making this a Wiki answer because I doubt I'll have time or access to experiment or to ever understand this conclusively.
Andrew asks: Is it a simple fridge or does it have some electronics in it, such as a digital temperature display? Maybe the electronics have a switched-mode PSU designed to use ground for EMI suppression. Without the ground connected to ground, there could be a noticeable voltage on the chassis
Answer: *This* fridge has an electronic front panel and LED lighting.

SMPS Noise suppression: Here is a decent article on SMPS noise suppression and leaking to ground.   There are a lot of really bad and misleading articles out there.  Watch out.  Basically there are articles like "Electricity!  Danger!  Double Insulation! It's all about safety!"  and then there are articles requiring at least two years of undergrad Electrical Engineering, but very little in between.  If you find a good "in between" article please add it here.
Zap Lap: I have experienced this! When a laptop computer is fed by a power brick with a two-pin electric plug, you wear shorts, put the laptop on your lap and feel a tingle from the screws on the bottom.  I have also experienced it with a three-pin brick plugged into a two-pin outlet.  It's unpleasantly painful.   Here is a blog by Dell themselves, acknowledging the problem and their fix, but using evasive and euphemistic language to avoid saying you are being subjected to electric shock.  Almost all newer laptop computers now come with three-pin power cords, where the third pin is bonded to the Negative side of the DC output.
It's very reasonable for the designer of a feature-packed modern fridge to assume it will be grounded properly, and design for that.   I have no proof yet and maybe next time I pull my own fridge out for cleaning I'll test it with a cheater plug for a little more evidence.

I'm not an electronics engineer, so I can't give a safe answer on what would happen with the equivalent of a laptop Type 1 mains adaptor used without the ground connection it's designed to use. My comment was speculation; maybe a qualified EE could comment here to confirm or refute that.
